# How to submit the form on new tab from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a form in iframe and need submit this form by taking it out from iframe possibly by using with `jQuery.`

This is my form's `HTML`:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank" id="paypal_form">
  <input type='hidden' name='some_value' id='some_value' value='151' />
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#paypal_form").submit();
```

But this does not seems to work. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have something like below. In order to submit form in new tab, you can clone iframe form to your page in a temp section, and use `target="_blank"` in form. And be sure that, iframe source is same with your domain. You cannot access a iframe hosted on another domain;

```
    <iframe src ="" width="100%" height="100%" id="iframe">
      <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank" id="paypal_form">
       <input type='hidden' name='some_value' id='some_value' value='151' />
      </form>
    </iframe>

<div id="temp_form"></div> <!-- this is temp form section -->
```

And you can use js like;

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('#paypal_form').appendTo("#temp_form");
$("#temp_form #paypal_form").submit();
```

Comment: @Chris I have updated my answer, cloned form to current page and submitted it